# Confusion of local declaration for map view kit

Tags: objective-c

I am working in Mapview. When I compile the code I get following warning:

```
local declaration of mapview hides instance
```

What  does it mean, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `self.mapView` inside your method.It says your local variable name and instance variable's are same. So you are getting this warning.

Otherwise change your local mapview's variable name (theMapView).

Comment: thanks for ur response,  it shows same warning when i am trying   this %self.mapView.annotations.count;

Comment: change your mapView's name in local method with theMapView. and this warning is not harmful for u.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning as your instance name is mapView.
if you want to remove this warning please use different name for your instance name like mMapView of aMapView in .h file

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a class :
`@interface yourClass : NSObject
{
 int theRank
}`
And you have a method:
`-(void)updateRank:(int)theRank
{
theRank++;
}`
How can you know if you're talking about theRank defined in your class or the local theRank argument of your method?
That why you get the same message as you got.
Solution : Rename your attribut or use `self.yourAttribut`